# Does the NodeJS debugger crash when using `this` to call an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I have a js file with the following content:

```
(function (context) {
    console.log(123);
    debugger;
})(this);
```

Then I run my script in debug mode:

```
$ node debug script.js
```

> [image]

Is there any reason for which the other lines in debug mode are not colored in green?

If inside of the function I do:

```
debug> repl
> context
{}
```

but when I do this:

```
> this
```

it crashes... Even pressing CTRL+C can't stop the process but only closing the tab.

Also, just adding `var foo = this` in the first line of the file fixes this behaviour.

Why? Is this a bug?

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Which version, are you using?

Comment: @thefourtheye `v0.10.24` Is this the latest stable version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same place where Node hangs when (in repl mode) you ask for the value of `this`, check the value of:

```
this === global
```

You should get `true`. Also, if you ask for the value of `global`, Node will hang just like it did for `this`. However you can access *some* fields without problem. I was able to access `this.module` (or `global.module`) and get a reasonable value.

So this looks like a bug, and I'd venture to say this is probably a bug with dealing with circular references. Generally, Node is able to handle them properly by displaying `[Circular]` but there seem to be a problem in the specific case at hand here.

Doing any of these will cause the debugger to print `{}` for `this` and not hang:

- Adding `"use strict";` at the start of the file.
- Adding `debugger;` as the first statement of the file.
- Adding a statement with side-effects like `console.log("start");` at the start of the file.

The following do not have any effect:

- Adding a statement that could conceivably be optimized away like `var x = 1;` or `function foo() {}` at the start of the file.
- This:

  ```
  var x = 1;

  (function (context) {
     console.log(123);
     debugger;
  })(this);

  console.log(x);
  ```

  The debugger stops on `var x = 1` so it is not like it is optimized away.

Comment: *The debugger stops on var `x = 1` so it is not like it is optimized away.* - from what I know, the debugger stops at the first line (even there is no breakpoint). Good answer!